# How to create a symmetrical Host - VM setup

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, host, guest

So I'm in a rather annoying situation where about half of the work I do requires a Linux based environment to work on, and the other half requires a Windows based environment. Unfortunately I need to switch between the environments on a regular basis and the time taken to re-boot into the other environment is quite prohibitive of this.

I have tried running Linux most of the time with a Windows VM to work in when necessary but I have found that to be quite restrictive in terms of performance, the same when running Windows as the host and Linux within a VM.

What I would like to do is set up my work machine to dual boot Windows and Linux alongside each other, but set up VMWare Workstation or a similar product to allow me to boot one partition as a VM while working in the other as a host, and vice versa with the other partition as the host and the first as a VM. Ideally this would allow using each host for it's main tasks and swapping to the VM when needed for quick things.

RAM isn't an issue on the machine, I have 16GB available and can get more if necessary (probably not) and both operating systems will run from an SSD with a HDD for data storage
, or being able to hibernate as the host and restart the machine 
Just to re-iterate, what I'm imagining is:

- /dev/sda1 - Windows C: drive
- /dev/sda2 - Linux / drive
- /dev/sdb1 - Linux /home drive
- /dev/sdb2 - Windows D: drive

Where both Windows C: and Linux / can be booted as both native host operating systems and as a guest inside the other.

Has anyone done a set up like this before? If so are there any guides you'd recommend?
What problems can people foresee happening?
Is there another possible solution that I'm missing?

I realise that this may not be the ideal solution, I've asked about getting multiple machines and a KVM but our IT administrator shot that idea down.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a solution that may be very specific to your instance.  I would pose the question of why running a VM is not working for you (in either instance of Win/Linux or Linux/Win).

I will give a few ideas just to toss around and see what might be the best solution for you.  Since I do not know what you use each OS for I'm going to just speculate a little bit.

**Idea 1:**
I would say almost everything in linux can be run from a console.  With that in mind typically I would setup a Windows computer running a VMWare Workstation or any other VM tool to run a instance of Linux on it.  With that I would just SSH into the VM through PuTTY and do the tasks at hand.  You could also go the extra step to setup VNC and X if you really need a full "desktop" environment.  I find running the OS is less of a issue but rather running the graphics/desktop.  Typically a VM software comes with a console view of the desktop but I find using RDP or VNC use less resources.

**Idea 2:**
You could do the same thing as Idea 1 but instead of running a VM you would run a linux emulator like Cygwin to run linux at the same time without needing to actually install a VM on VM Software.  Since I do not know what you use each OS for it would really change the solution a bit.

**Side Note:** with both 1 or 2 I believe **Windows** being the one needing a full Desktop environment it would be the preferred OS to be the Host.

**Idea 3:**
Run a full KVM type server such as Unraid.  This would require 3 graphic cards + at least 3 HDDs and it would take a bit of configuration but it can run Unraid + Windows (Monitor 0) + Linux (Monitor 1) and each OS would have a dedicated graphics card to point to.  You can probably YouTube how to do this (people make single machine multi gaming rigs with this).

Hope this all helps :)